# Writing a custom-formatted toString method for a matrix. Need it to accept either Integer or Double

Tags: java, generics, input, arraylist, subtyping

For now input is restricted to the form of `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` or `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`. I understand that `ArrayList<Integer>` is not a subclass of `ArrayList<Number>`, and when I try to use `ArrayList<?>` or `ArrayList<? extends Number>` the other known errors occur with adding (namely that they're not superclasses either AND the runtime-adding issue). Yes, I could just make two copies of the method, one for `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` and one for `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`, but that's ugly for other reasons. Similarly, converting to arrays or making my own custom matrix class.

I've seen lots of posts on this problem, but no solutions anywhere except to rewrite large sections of code. Is there any simple answer in Java for how to write a method that can accept both of those as input?

I've tried everything I can think of. That's why I'm here. I can't even create a helper method to break out the inner ArrayLists, since that method would itself have to accept one of the aforementioned inputs.

The current code, if it helps:

```
static String integerMatrixToString(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix) {
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.get(0).size(); j++) {    
        ArrayList<Integer> n = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
            n.add(matrix.get(i).get(j));
        }
        s.add(myArrayListToString(n, ParseType.EMPTY_EMPTY_SPACE));
    }
    return myArrayListToString(s, ParseType.EMPTY_EMPTY_NEWLINE);
}
```

Comment: You mention ArrayList<ArrayList> twice as if they where to different things. Could this be a mistake?

Comment: Why not use: ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<? extends Number>>

Comment: You should write the method to accept `List<? extends List<? extends Number>>`, rather than `ArrayList`; because there's _almost never_ a good reason to restrict it to just ArrayList over any other kind of List.

Comment: I don't really understand the thing about the custom-formatted `toString` method - are you wanting to do a specific thing for `Integer` and a specific thing for `Double`, or are you just invoking `toString()` on the elements? (If you're just invoking `toString()`, there's no need to restrict to `Integer` and `Double`)

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, need a custom formatted toString method, as in different output than the default toString. But no, it does the same thing for both Double and Integer, namely printing them in the chosen format.

Comment: As far as wildcarding the List/ArrayList, tried both, but it has the same issue with adding I mentioned: "The method add(capture#11-of ? extends Number) in the type ArrayList<capture#11-of ? extends Number> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#13-of ? extends Number)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by making the method generic, with a type parameter `N extends Numeric`. Here is a complete example:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NumberFormatter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> intMatrix = List.of(
                List.of(1, 2),
                List.of(3, 4)
        );
        /*
         * 1 3
         * 2 4
         */
        List<List<Double>> doubleMatrix = List.of(
                List.of(5.6, 7.8),
                List.of(9.0, 1.2)
        );
        /*
         * 5.6 9.0
         * 7.8 1.2
         */
        System.out.println(matrixToString(intMatrix));
        System.out.println(matrixToString(doubleMatrix));
    }

    static <N> String matrixToString(List<? extends List<N>> matrix) {
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.get(0).size(); j++) {
            List<N> n = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
                n.add(matrix.get(i).get(j));
            }
            s.add(myArrayListToString(n, ParseType.EMPTY_EMPTY_SPACE));
        }
        return myArrayListToString(s, ParseType.EMPTY_EMPTY_NEWLINE);
    }

    private static String myArrayListToString(List<?> nums, ParseType parseType) {
        return nums.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(parseType.delimiter));
    }

    private enum ParseType {
        EMPTY_EMPTY_NEWLINE("\n"), EMPTY_EMPTY_SPACE(" ");

        private final String delimiter;

        private ParseType(String delimiter) {
            this.delimiter = delimiter;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the behaviour of transposing the matrix in the output was in the original code provided, so I assumed that this is intentional and preserved this behaviour.

Also, there's nothing in this implementation of `matrixToString` that actually requires the data in the matrix to be numeric, as the only method called on each cell is `Object.toString()`. If you wish to allow any type of data in the matrix, simply remove `extends Number` from the type parameter, and the method will have the same behaviour for numeric types while also allowing other types.

Comment: Holy crap you're a mensch!! Thank you!!! Messed around w wildcards and generics, but just didn't get the right combo and didn't know how. This is such a huge help, I have several methods that can benefit from this, Thank You!!